# Apple Push Notifications: Not receiving device token?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

In an app which involves push notifications, I am receiving device tokens just fine but the my client's device doesn't receive device token (hence causing failure to receive push notifications). I am using Parse for push notifications. This is what I have in my `AppDelegate`:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    PFACL *objectACL = [[PFACL alloc] init];
    [objectACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    [objectACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error];
    UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [errorAlertView show];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APPLICATION_ID
                  clientKey:PARSE_CUSTOMER_KEY];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // create the Login controller instance:

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

Client doesn't receive any UIAlert representing failure of registration with APN so that means `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is not being called. I have tried removing all installations from my parse server, removing the app & reinstalling again as per guidelines of Apple technical note TN2265. The application doesn't prompt the client for authorization of push notifications on first launch & doesn't appear in notification center either (Which is baffling because `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` is there too). But all this is working fine on my iPad, iPhone 5S, iPod 5, iPhone 4s. Any ideas what Might be causing this device to device variable behavior in the app?!This is the sc client sent me.[notificationCenterScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwAtx.png)

Comment: Can you show me how you have registered for push notification?

Comment: I added the didFinish method too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

within `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method in your AppDelegate class

Comment: but that's for iOS 8 and backward compatibility I assume?

Comment: @NSNoob Yes but from iOS 8 you have to use registerUserNotificationSettings method to set notification types and then you have to call registerForRemoteNotifications method to register it.

Comment: Well yeah that's a possibility he might be testing the app on a device with iOS 8. I will have to wait for his response, if that's the solution i will mark it as correct answer, Thank you.

Comment: Not yet the guy's on holidays so he is not responding. Don't worry as soon as i get the word, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah that guy told me he was using iOS 7 while infact he was using iOS 8 which was causing all the issues. Thanks