# Development Apple Push Notifications aren't working on iOS; didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have an app which works on iOS 7 and later. Apple Push Notifications were working in development mode yesterday, but not now.

I am registering for push notifications like this:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        //enabled =  [application isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        //UIRemoteNotificationType types = [application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        //enabled = types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;

    }

// Delegate methods are

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{

    NSString *newToken = [deviceToken description];

    newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

    newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    self.myDeviceToken = newToken;
    [CLServerDataManager setDeviceToken:newToken];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
    [CLServerDataManager setDeviceToken:@"dummy"];
    self.myDeviceToken = @"dummy";
#endif

}
```

And push notifications were working till last day. Certificates were made according to the www.raywenderlich.com site.

But now I have noticed that methods:

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
```

are not being called and I am **not getting the device token.

I am trying this code as well:

```
NSUUID *identifierForVendor = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *deviceId = [identifierForVendor UUIDString];
```

... and both are not working.

Please let me know what could be the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Push notifications is allowed in settings?

Comment: Device token is not your UUID. Device Token is retrieved from APNS after your user allows the App to send push notifications.

Comment: Follow step by step in [push notifications tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)

Comment: Register your device for Push in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method using the [code here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729129/apple-push-notifications-not-receiving-device-token). After that your `didRegisterForRemote` or `didFailRegister` methods will be called

Comment: Are you using proper APN certificates? Are they properly configured on the server?

Comment: Hello all,
Thanks for your response

push notification is allowed in settings.

I noticed now that device token is generated but
when i try with another device it doesn't don't know why in Xcode?

Comment: @GopalDevra You can't test Push notifications in Simulator if thats what you mean. You can send push via sim but cant receive them.

Comment: @NSNoob
I am debugging with real device.

Comment: Then add the code of how you are registering for push and how have you configured your certificates

Comment: On the request of @Noob 
I have added the code please have a look.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. Known-good code (a tagged build from weeks ago) no longer receives a device token (nor the failure callback) when working vs. development/sandbox APNS. Production builds on the same code are working fine.

Comment: I am also have similar problem since last day. Can't receive device token on iOS 9. I receive device token on iOS 8.3.1 but submitted notifications is not delivered

Comment: same here! not working exactly as you described for 5hrs now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896861/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-stopped-being-called?noredirect=1#comment61362434_36896861