# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken stopped being called

Tags: swift, push-notification

I am testing my app for using Push Notifs. It worked well the whole day and suddenly it stopped. No changes in the setup at all. After debugging a bit more, I found out, that the function `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` never gets called anymore. I set a breakpoint at this function and it is not called at all when the app starts up, or I re-install the app. I get the actionsheet if I want to allow push notifs, but the delegate is never called afterwards.

```
    settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings!)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: same thing happened to me today

Comment: what? Really? Like out of the blue? I checked the apple services: They are all online.

Comment: Wow, I've spent the whole day on the same issue and still couldn't figure out what happened!

Comment: hahaha! awesome. I am just sitting here for 3 hrs taking apart my whole app and questioning my mind....

Comment: I followed along with this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG21 going to debug the persistent connection with the apn server but I have found nothing interesting. Seems that the connection has been established

Comment: Yes.. thats true! I tested with APN Tester application. All went well. Connection is fine, data delivered. I really think Apple must be the reason right now

Comment: did you check your code signing settings? provisioning profile? debugging with a new device? had someone on the team clicking on 'fix issue' in Xcode?

Comment: yep, yep, yep, I am the only one in the team

Comment: the code base has not changed during the whole day expect for UI changes. And 3 hrs. ago I'd say, maybe two, everything went dead

Comment: the system status on apple shows all gree though.. I don't get it

Comment: did you have the same experience that your push notifs are not being received anymore today?

Comment: Here it stopped working about 5 hours ago. No changes in code, profiles, nothing.

Comment: So usually I would expect if the delegate is not called, that the failedRegisterForRemoteNotifications is supposed to be called and return an error. Not happening as well

Comment: So... I feel not good about the idea that just waiting is the answer and apple services are all green right now. I would expect a flood of people complaining on SO :) What concerns me more, is that not even an error is thrown somewhere in the app

Comment: Same experience bro.

Comment: not great but good to hear that the code seems ok

Comment: Ditto on all counts. No longer getting `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` calls. `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` not called either.

Comment: Same experience for me

Comment: Same exact thing just happened to me about 2 hours ago. I still can't figure out why the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not getting called. Please let me know if you figured out the answer!!

Comment: I sell my soul if this is not a bug within APNS.......

Comment: I went through every component relevant again. No error... and no change on the apple service status website. Why are not more people affected than just us?

Comment: I would try it again tomorrow and if it doesn't work and it was working fine before you made any changes to your code, send in a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I did not remotely touched the functionality on my notifications. After a few hours now I will file a bug report.

Comment: I think its an APNS bug also! I will try again in a few hours

Comment: This happens only under development. I've tested using the app in the app from the store and it registered its token to the server. But it didn't work with the testflight version (which should be using production apns too).

Comment: I stopped using testflight and changed to crashalytics, but still having the same issue

Comment: So with all the info we have it seems that the APNS Sandbox is down but not reporting an error.. and system status tracking is not the highest prio as it seems for apple right now :)

Comment: Yes, i think you are right

Comment: I think apple just fixed this issue. I am now getting the token!

Comment: confirm. Issue fixed! Hell! I trashed half a work day. <3 love apple

Comment: hahaha! same here! all back working! And half day of work just gone....

Comment: I am getting the same issue today. My code was working perfectly fine till yesterday but today the function   "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is not getting called. Please help me with the fix. Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue too. It worked perfectly few days ago (have been developing other things until today) but now, no token, no calling didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken... Quite frustrating

Comment: Just restart your device!!!

Comment: restarting device also not working...